# SailsJS - Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/.babel.json'

Tags: node.js, sails.js, babeljs, package.json

I'm working on at a SailsJS project and when I push it to serverI get the error

```
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1347:33)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
at save (/usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/cache.js:48:16)
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/.babel.json'
```

I know the server call babeljs on build and I think the error can be by the babeljs being called in the build and by the sailsjs when it starts, that is, twice.

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/rauchg/slackin/issues/144) about the error, but I can't disable the babeljs cache on my server.

My **Package.json is**:

```
{
  "name": "cards",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "a Sails-Redux application for multi-player online card game",
  "keywords": [
    "sailsjs",
    "redux",
    "es2015",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.13.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.11.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.13.0",
    "connect-mongo": "0.8.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ejs": "2.3.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-babel": "^6.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "0.13.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.5.3",
    "grunt-sails-linker": "~0.10.1",
    "grunt-sync": "0.2.4",
    "include-all": "~0.1.6",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "postcss-modules-extract-imports": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-modules-scope": "^1.0.0",
    "rc": "1.0.1",
    "react": "^0.14.9",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.9",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.8",
    "react-router": "^2.6.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^0.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^5.3.2",
    "redux-optimist": "0.0.2",
    "redux-optimistic-ui": "^0.3.2",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-undo": "^0.6.1",
    "sails": "~0.12.1",
    "sails-disk": "~0.10.9",
    "sails-hook-babel": "^6.0.1",
    "sails-mongo": "^0.12.2",
    "sails-webpack": "^1.0.13",
    "sass": "^0.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "unexpected-react": "^1.0.0",
    "updeep": "^0.16.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "node debug app.js",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "fernando",
  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "css-modules-require-hook": "^4.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "react-tools": "^0.13.3",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "source-map": "^0.5.3",
    "unexpected": "^10.10.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it an option for you to `sails lift` as root? (or using sudo)?

Answer (score 0):

When you push it to the server, I image you use Git and then you do a npm update/install. If so, you might want to check the permissions on your app folder before running npm install. Sorry, I cannot write this in a comment...